# Prevent padding from causing element to overflow its parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my HTML structure:

```css
.parent{
  background-color:#f7f7f7;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border:2px solid;
}

.child{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:#cf5;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">something</div>
</div>
```

As you see `div.child` goes out of `div.parent`. That's because of `padding: 15px;`. Well, how can I calculate this in CSS:

```
.child{
    height: (100% - the number of padding);
    width: (100% - the number of padding);
}
```

So this is expected result: *(noted that there also should be `padding: 15px`)*

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Just add `box-sizing: border-box` to the child element.

```css
.parent {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid;
}
.child {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #cf5;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* NEW */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">something</div>
</div>
```

The [**CSS `box-sizing` property**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) has an initial value of `content-box`. This means the box model calculates total width by adding the content *plus* padding *plus* borders. The calculation is similar for height.

With `border-box`, the box model includes padding and borders in the `width` / `height` calculation.

(Note that margins are always outside the calculation; they will be appended whether in `content-box` or `border-box`.)

---

A second possibility (arguably less efficient than `box-sizing`) would be the [**CSS `calc` function**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc):

```css
.parent {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid;
}
.child {
  height: calc(100% - 30px);  /* NEW */
  width: calc(100% - 30px);   /* NEW */
  background-color: #cf5;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">something</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah that's correct, upvote .. but not perfect. Because the most of my website's users use old browsers like IE7, and as you know it doesn't support CSS3 `:-(`

Comment: @stack IE8 supports it (this box model was introduced by IE). Are you sure you want to support IE7? Even its support for the simplest CSS 2 is disastrous.

Comment: @Oriol *"Even its support for the simplest CSS 2 is disastrous"* .. Actually you have to say that to my website's users ..!

Comment: @stack, you know that `box-sizing: border-box` emulates old IE browsers in quirks mode, right? So, remove your doctype... Haha!! TOTALLY KIDDING. Maybe consider a [**polyfill**](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/box-sizing-polyfills/).

Answer (score 0):

Use a margin instead:

```
.child{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:#cf5;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the width, height, and margin in the child class. The parent class is just the wrapper it only needs styles that are specific to it. i.e. The background color and the border.

```
.parent{
  background-color:#f7f7f7;
  border:2px solid;
}

.child{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color:#cf5;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

The child class pushes out of the parent because you set its dimensions to be fixed and the child to 100% of that. You then set the padding which push the child out of the parent.

Comment: Wrong .. the final `width` and `height` will be `115px` in your case.

Comment: Yes. Your right. It will be 115px because it adds the child class padding to that calculated by the 100% setting of the parent which is 100 and 100 plus 15 is 115